# tabwidget icon align text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, android-tabs

Hello I have already a code for tabs layout using tab widget in android, each tab has their own activity but I'm getting this:

How I can move down the text circle in red?

Here is my code:

**main activity:**

```
package com.example.androidtablayout;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("En Vivo");
        photospec.setIndicator("En Vivo", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_songs_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

        // Tab for Songs
        TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Twitter");
        // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
        songspec.setIndicator("Twitter", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
        songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contactenos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Contactenos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
        tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
}
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

thank you very much.

Comment: means u want to down tabwidget or text? im confused what is ur requiremnet???

Comment: down the text so it shows icon and text clearly, but i dont know what to do for move the text down its possible?

Comment: add some space to <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp" />

Comment: doesnt move the text itself just the whole tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have did this to make image and text align over tabs :

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
            {
                TextView tv = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
                tv.setShadowLayer(2, 2, 2, Color.BLACK);
            }
```

set the padding as per your requirement.

to set the height of tabs :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tab1=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tab2=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tab3=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tab4=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tab5=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams();

            tab1.setMargins(10, 10, 5, 0);
            tab2.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 0);
            tab3.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 0);
            tab4.setMargins(5, 10, 10, 0);
            tab5.setMargins(0, 10, 10, 0);
```

Comment: works, but now text is cutting down, how can i set more height to all my tabs? thank you

Comment: ya i have solution for this  also

Comment: sounds good, why this happens? i tried many tutorials all have the same issue at least for me